# Recursion in pyQT6, self.scene.setSceneRect(adjusted)

Tags: python, recursion, pyqt6

Its my first time programming object oriented and I cant seem to find a recursion in my program. Probably its in the last line because the software prints my debug number 3 but not 4.
If somebody could help me out it would be phantastic.
The code is supposed to show a bezier curve with the control points which can be moved around. If the curve exceeds the original size `setSceneRect` makes the scene larger. The error is probably there I guess!

main.py

```
import sys
import PyQt6.QtCore
import PyQt6.QtWidgets
import PyQt6.QtGui
import bezier


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PyQt6.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    cArray = [
        bezier.Curve(
            PyQt6.QtCore.QPointF(50, 200),
            PyQt6.QtCore.QPointF(200, 50),
            PyQt6.QtCore.QPointF(400, 350),
            PyQt6.QtCore.QPointF(550, 200),
        )
    ]
    
    window = bezier.Widget()
    window.show()
    window.draw(cArray)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

bezier.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsEllipseItem,
    QGraphicsItem,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QGraphicsPathItem
)

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QRectF
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPen, QColor, QPainterPath, QWheelEvent, QBrush


class ControlPoint(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, parent, point):
        super().__init__()

        self.point = point
        self.parent = parent

        self.setRect(point.x() - 5, point.y() - 5, 10, 10)
        brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        self.setBrush(brush)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        self.point = QPointF(event.scenePos())
        event.accept()
        event.ignore()
        self.parent.drawCurve()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.point = QPointF(event.scenePos())
        self.parent.drawCurve()


class Curve:
    def __init__(self, point1, point2, point3, point4):
        super().__init__()
        self.curve_item = None
        self.Widget = None
        self.path = None

        self.control_points = [
            ControlPoint(self, point1),
            ControlPoint(self, point2),
            ControlPoint(self, point3),
            ControlPoint(self, point4),
        ]

    def setWidget(self, Widget):
        self.Widget = Widget

    def drawPoints(self):
        if not self.Widget:
            raise Exception("Widget used before initialized")
        for point in self.control_points:
            self.Widget.scene.addItem(point)

    def drawCurve(self):
        if not self.Widget:
            raise Exception("Widget used before initialized")
        self.path = QPainterPath()

        control_point_scale = 0.5
        scaled_control_points = [
            QPointF(self.control_points[0].point),
            QPointF(
                self.control_points[0].point
                + (
                    (self.control_points[1].point - self.control_points[0].point)
                    / control_point_scale
                )
            ),
            QPointF(
                self.control_points[3].point
                + (
                    (self.control_points[2].point - self.control_points[3].point)
                    / control_point_scale
                )
            ),
            QPointF(self.control_points[3].point)
        ]

        self.path.moveTo(self.control_points[0].point)

        for i in range(1, len(scaled_control_points), 3):
            if i + 2 < len(scaled_control_points):
                self.path.cubicTo(
                    scaled_control_points[i],
                    scaled_control_points[i + 1],
                    scaled_control_points[i + 2],
                )

        if not isinstance(self.curve_item, QGraphicsPathItem):
            self.curve_item = self.Widget.scene.addPath(self.path, QPen(QColor(0, 0, 255), 2))
            self.Widget.scene.addItem(self.curve_item)

        self.curve_item.setPath(self.path)
        self.curve_item.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 255), 2))
        self.Widget.resizeScreen()




class View(QGraphicsView):
    def wheelEvent(self, event: QWheelEvent):
        # Ignore the wheel event to prevent zooming
        Widget().resizeScreen()
        event.ignore()


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Setup Screen
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view = View(self.scene)
        self.setWindowTitle("Bezier Curve")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        # Setup Layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

    def draw(self, curveArray):
        for curve in curveArray:
            curve.setWidget(self)
            curve.drawCurve()
            curve.drawPoints()

    def wheelEvent(self, event: QWheelEvent):
        # Zoom in/out on wheel event
        super().wheelEvent(event)
        factor = 1.2
        if event.angleDelta().y() < 0:
            factor = 1.0 / factor

        self.view.scale(factor, factor)
        self.resizeScreen()

    def resizeScreen(self):
        # Resize screen
        items = self.scene.items()
        print(1)
        if not items:
            return
        scene_rect = items[0].sceneBoundingRect()
        print(2)
        for item in items[1:]:
            scene_rect = scene_rect.united(item.sceneBoundingRect())
            print(item)
        
        # Set the calculated sceneRect
        padding = 0
        adjusted = scene_rect.adjusted(-padding, -padding, padding, padding)
        print(3)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(adjusted)
        print(4)
```

Last log entrys+Traceback:

```
1
2
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E71C0>
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E7130>
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E6C20>
<PyQt6.QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem object at 0x00000230B68E75B0>
3
1
2
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E71C0>
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E7130>
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E6C20>
<PyQt6.QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem object at 0x00000230B68E75B0>
3
1
2
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E71C0>
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E7130>
<bezier.ControlPoint object at 0x00000230B68E6C20>
<PyQt6.QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem object at 0x00000230B68E75B0>
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Nextcloud\prog\Car\car_system_sim\bezier.py", line 33, in mouseMoveEvent
  File "d:\Nextcloud\prog\Car\car_system_sim\bezier.py", line 105, in drawCurve
  File "d:\Nextcloud\prog\Car\car_system_sim\bezier.py", line 147, in resizeScreen
  File "d:\Nextcloud\prog\Car\car_system_sim\bezier.py", line 147, in resizeScreen
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
PS D:\Nextcloud\prog\Car\car_system_sim>
```

t doesnt get stuck at the beginning of the code. I get my debug numbers from 1-4 but at the end, it only writes 1-3 so there has to be a problem in setSceneRect(). All the errors happen if I am outside of the window. I want to make it work there to!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changing the scene rect may cause adjustments in the origin point of the scene in the view (typically, changing the scene origin point when it is *within* the viewport margins): since that will potentially "scroll" the scene, the result is that you get an indirect mouse movement for the item, because scrolling the scene moves the item and, therefore, the mouse position relative to it. You could set a "recursion guard" (a bool instance attribute) within `resizeScreen()` that will immediately return whenever it's `True`, otherwise set it to `True` before `setSceneRect` and unset it right after.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only solve your current issue, but you'll probably get more problems in the foreseeable future due to important issues in your code, mostly related to event handling; for instance: 1. clueless event `ignore()` and `accept()` calls; 2. similarly, calling the base implementation of event handlers while *also* overriding its behavior furthermore; 3. that `Widget().resizeScreen()` in the `wheelEvent()` of `View`, which makes absolutely no sense. I strongly recommend you to carefully study the [event system documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/eventsandfilters.html)).

Comment: I edited my code from before, actually point 1 and 3 were relicts of earlier tests. I dont really get the second point. Should I collect all mouse Events and if the right one ist triggered handle it myself and if not pass the event to the base class? The recursion guard worked perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: Exactly: whenever `super().<eventHandler>(event)` is called, you are actually following the default behavior, meaning that it will do what is normally done without the override, including accepting/ignoring the event. Most importantly, if you ignore an event that the base implementation otherwise accepts (or vice versa), that may result in unexpected behavior, because parent objects may behave differently depending on the *expected* event acceptance. OTOH, events that shouldn't be propagated to the parent should normally be accepted, which is the opposite of what did in `wheelEvent` of `View`.

Comment: For future reference, always take your time to carefully craft valid and foolproof examples (taking care of "relics" that may even cause further issues): never rush publishing. If you found a valid solution, I suggest you to post your own answer. Keep in mind, though, that a proper implementation of the above should use a parent QGraphicsPathItem with the control points set as its children. See these partially related posts: 1. [Spline Editor in PyQt5 QGraphicsView](//stackoverflow.com/q/77111404) 2. [Add Mouse Motion functionality to PyQt based Bezier Drawer](//stackoverflow.com/q/71191764)

Comment: I've looked it up and stumbled upon this [post](https://www.qt.io/blog/input-events-in-qt-6) how do I catch all input events?

Comment: Also I changed the code again: the new mouse...Event have the super() removed and a BaseClass.mouse...Event(event) added. Also the whellEvent gets accepted not ignored. Is this what you thought of?